# JavaScript sort date according to week and month to sum up the amount

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I am trying to sort the profit for this week, last week, this month and last month from an array. The sameple data:

```
var arr = [{date: '2017/12/16',  profit: 12.50},
{date: '2017/05/01', profit: 13.50},
{date: '2017/04/20', profit: 14.50},
{date: '2017/03/10', profit: 15.50},
{date: '2017/08/15', profit: 16.50},
{date: '2017/08/16', profit: 26.50},
{date: '2017/08/24', profit: 16.50},
{date: '2017/08/25', profit: 36.50},
{date: '2017/03/06', profit: 17.50},
{date: '2017/02/04', profit: 18.50},
{date: '2017/01/07', profit: 19.50}];
```

I wanted to sort and get the profit according to this week/last week/this month/last month. I have tried with getting today and yesterday's profit with this:

```
var today = getTodayDate();
var todayProfit = 0;

for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
if(arr[i].date == today){
    todayProfit = arr[i].total;
    break;
}
}
```

Same goes for yesterday which I basically get the yesterday's date. How can I actually sort for this week/last week/this month/last month? Do I have to create another array to get all the dates and do nested for loop?

Is there any better approach?

Desired output:

```
This week profit: 53.00
Last week profit: 43.00
This month profit: 96.00
Last month profit: 0.00
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To sort by date, use `arr.sort()`, which will sort it in place so you won't need another array :

```
arr.sort(function(a,b){
    return new Date(a.date)-new Date(b.date);
});
```

And if you like short code, use an arrow function :

```
arr.sort((a,b)=>new Date(a.date)-new Date(b.date));
```

Then, for figuring this/last week/month, use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/):

```js
var arr = [
  {date: '2017/12/16',  profit: 12.50},
  {date: '2017/05/01', profit: 13.50},
  {date: '2017/04/20', profit: 14.50},
  {date: '2017/03/10', profit: 15.50},
  {date: '2017/08/15', profit: 16.50},
  {date: '2017/08/16', profit: 26.50},
  {date: '2017/08/24', profit: 16.50},
  {date: '2017/08/25', profit: 36.50},
  {date: '2017/03/06', profit: 17.50},
  {date: '2017/02/04', profit: 18.50},
  {date: '2017/01/07', profit: 19.50}
];

var profits = [0,0,0,0]; // this/last week, this/last month
var date;

function isThisWeek(d) {
  // start and end of this week
  var thisWeek = [moment().utc().startOf('week'),
                  moment().utc().endOf('week')];
  return d.isBetween(thisWeek[0],thisWeek[1])||
  d.isSame(thisWeek[0])||
  d.isSame(thisWeek[1]);
}

function isLastWeek(d) {
  // start and end of this week minus 1, which is last week
  var lastWeek = [moment().utc().subtract(1,'weeks').startOf('week'),
                  moment().utc().subtract(1,'weeks').endOf('week')];
  return d.isBetween(lastWeek[0],lastWeek[1])||
  d.isSame(lastWeek[0])||
  d.isSame(lastWeek[1]);
}

function isThisMonth(d) {
  // start and end of this month
  var thisMonth = [moment().utc().startOf('month'),
                   moment().utc().endOf('month')];
  return d.isBetween(thisMonth[0],thisMonth[1])||
  d.isSame(thisMonth[0])||
  d.isSame(thisMonth[1]);
}

function isLastMonth(d) {
  // start and end of this month minus 1, which is last month
  var lastMonth = [moment().subtract(1,'months').utc().startOf('month'),
                   moment().subtract(1,'months').utc().endOf('month')];
  return d.isBetween(lastMonth[0],lastMonth[1])||
  d.isSame(lastMonth[0])||
  d.isSame(lastMonth[1]);
}
arr.forEach(function(e){
  date=moment.utc(e.date,'YYYY-MM-DD');
  if (isThisWeek(date)) { // if it's this week
    profits[0]+=e.profit;
  } else if (isLastWeek(date)) { // if it's last week
    profits[1]+=e.profit;
  }
  if (isThisMonth(date)) { // if it's this month
    profits[2]+=e.profit;
  } else if (isLastMonth(date)) { // if it's last month
    profits[3]+=e.profit;
  }
});
console.log("This week profits : "+profits[0]);
console.log("Last week profits : "+profits[1]);
console.log("This month profits : "+profits[2]);
console.log("Last month profits : "+profits[3]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Sorry but what I meant is I wanted to group the profit according to criteria like this week, last week, this month and last month.

Comment: What is the desired output exactly? an array, an object, variables for each criteria?

Comment: Yeah it should be just a number for each criteria. I have updated the question!

Comment: What do you mean by this week/month last week/month, are they just today(+-)7/today(+-)30?

Comment: Yeap I did it with the help of some libraries to get the date. Thanks!

Comment: Good for you, I also updated my solution, which works using `moment.js`.

Comment: Hey how do you calculate for today and yesterday? For today one, is it just if (today.diff(date, days) === 0) {} whereas for yesterday one, if (today.diff(date, days) === 1) {}  ?

Comment: Yes, but add quotations around days, so : `if (today.diff(date, "days") === 1) {}`.

Comment: hey I realized for this line: if (today.diff(date, 'months') === 0) {} it actually takes in the previous month also. Any ideas? Liek for example, current is september, when i try to get for this month, it actually return me both the august and september one. Then when I try to get last month, it actually return me the July one.

Comment: Like for example, today is 04/09/17, from your example, the amount for last week should be 0. but somehow it went two weeks backwards

Comment: Just to check with you, for this moment js right, let's say by the code above, I get the last month based on today's date, which in this case is the range of 30 days before today's date? For example, 04/09/17 which is today. The last month returned is the entire August starting from 01/08/17 to 31/08/17 or starting from 03/08/17 to 04/09/17? Same goes for week, is it based on the calendar's week or 7 days before the current date?

Comment: @guest176969 I explain in the updated answer, where I use `startOf('week')`, `endOf('week')`, `startOf('month')` and `endOf('month')` to determine this/last week/month.

Comment: so if I wanted to get the dates for last two week, I just subtract by 2. Am I right?

Comment: Ah nevermind, I tested it and the data are finally correct! Thanks!!!! But just a quick check with you regarding the updated solution, what you trying to do is get the start and end date of the week based on locale time, store them as array. Then, you check against the parameter date with the start/end date in the array or if the parameter date is between the the start/end dates?

Comment: @guest176969 , You're correct about subtracting 2, and I check if the date is between the start/end or if it's start or end, because isBetween is exclusive, so it checks only whether `start < date < end`, so you need another check for when `date==start` or `date==end` to make sure they're in one week.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to sort. You just need to check for current day, yesterday, or this month, and sum up the values when iterating:

```
 const today = "2017/08/26", yesterday = " 2017/08/25";
 const month = today.substr(0,-3);

 //results
 let profit = {
  today:0,
  yesterday:0,
  month:0
 };

arr.forEach(({date,profit}) =>{
 if(date === today) profit.today += profit;
 if(date === yesterday) profit.yesterday += profit;
 if(date.substr(0,-3) === month) profit.month += profit;
});

console.log( profit );
```

Comment: Sorry for my bad English. But is there any way to get the porfit for this week, last week, current month and last month?

Comment: @guest176969 thats what it does? Have you at least tried it?

Comment: Yeap I did it with the help of some libraries to get the date. Thanks!